# Wordpress and openx htaccess confusion

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress install in the root: domain.com

and I installed OpenX in a sub-directory, I installed it without any problem, and I can access the admin panel and everything without any problem, but when I try to access the following URL's

`https://domain.com/ads/www/admin/plugins/videoReport/players.php`, I get Wordpress 404

When I try to access only the directory `https://domain.com/ads/www/admin/plugins/videoReport`
I can see the php files, and folders listed.

I added in Wordpress htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ads|ads/.*)$
```

but without any success

EDIT:
I added the following htaccess file in ads directory:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Openx installed plugins with the following permissions:
folders -> 777
files -> 777

I chmoded via FTP all directories to 755, and all files to 644, and the plugins worked without any problem, it was not an htaccess problem